# Symmetry center of hexagon

Tags: polygons

How to show that the figure has a symmetry center for instance if we have a convex hexagon where opposite sides are of equal lenght and parallel?

Comment: Isn't it visually obvious? Also, you can prove it using the fact that the vertices are given by $(\mbox{Cos}(2\pi k/6),\mbox{Sin}(2\pi k/6))$ for integer $k$, and the fact that negating the entries of the vector yields $(\mbox{Cos}(2\pi (k+3)/6),\mbox{Sin}(2\pi (k+3)/6))$ after applying the usual trigonometric formulae.

Comment: yes it is, but I wonder how looks the mathematical proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the given information, the vertices of the given hexagon are
$$
p,\quad p+u,\quad p+u+v,\quad p+u+v+w,\quad p+v+w,\quad p+w
$$
for some $p,u,v,w\in\mathbb{R}^2$.  Then the symmetry center is
$$
p + \frac12(u+v+w).
$$

Comment: I have question what means $\mathbb{R}^2$? And later how you calculate the symmetry center? Have you been using any theorem for this?

Comment: Here $\mathbb{R}^2$ means the space of all $2$-dimensional vectors whose entries are real numbers.  The given point is the symmetry center because the set of vertices of the hexagon is closed under reflection across this point.

Comment: so for instace $p$ I can interpret as $p=(x_p,y_p)$ ?

Comment: Yes, $p$ is a vector with two components, as are $u$, $v$, and $w$.